# How to troubleshoot error code 2 and reason code 2400 in IBM JDK 8 and IBM MQ v8 when retrieving messages?

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq

I am receiving the error code 2 and the reason code 2400 (MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE) while attempting to retrieve a message using the IBM JDK 8 and IBM MQ v8. Can someone please help me identify the issue with my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/home/oracle/cert/jks/cert.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keytStorePassword", "changeit");
        //System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        String str1 = "hostname.com";
        String str2 = "1400";
        String str3 = "TEST.1";
        String str4 = "QMG2";
        String str5 = "P.OUT.TRD";
        try {
            MQEnvironment.hostname = "hostname.com";
            MQEnvironment.port = Integer.valueOf(str2).intValue();
            MQEnvironment.channel = str3;
            MQEnvironment.userID = "username";
            MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384";
            MQEnvironment.properties.put("transport", "MQSeries");
            MQQueueManager mQQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(str4);
            System.out.println("Connected to QMGR ");
            byte b = 16;
            MQQueue mQQueue = mQQueueManager.accessQueue(str5, b, null, null, null);
            i = mQQueue.getCurrentDepth();
            System.out.println(i);
            mQQueue.close();
            mQQueueManager.disconnect();
        } catch (MQException mQException) {
            mQException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving error code 2 and reason code 2400 while attempting to retrieve a message using the IBM JDK 8 and IBM MQ v8. Can someone please help me identify the issue with my code?

Comment: And so what does error 2 / reason 2400 mean? One reason to buy that IBM stuff is that is usually quite well documented...

Comment: MQRC 2400 means unsupport cipher suite, See here for list of supported ones https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=java-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes

Answer (score 1):

A MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE arises when
the ciphersuite specified in the program is unknown either at the MQ client or the Java JRE.

The usual explanation is a difference in the ciphersuite names
between the IBM MQ JRE and a non-IBM JRE. See - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-tls-connection-mq-failing-compcode-2-mqccfailed-reason-2400-mqrcunsupportedciphersuite-exception

From the above link:

> To disable the ciphersuite mappings for a non-IBM runtime
> environments, the following Java System Property must be set:
>
> com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
>
> For example, this can be configured by using the JVM argument:
>
> -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false

As `SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` is an IBM JRE CipherSuite name. The likelihood is that when you are running your application, it is using a non-IBM JRE. To verify add your logging equivalent of

```
        logger.info("Running under Java " + System.getProperty("java.version") 
                            + " from " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
```

I suspect that that isn't going to report IBM, but if it does then
for a `2400` there are unlikely to be any server logs (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=problems-tls-troubleshooting#q123400___title__12)

The above link says that a `2400` could be caused by a FIPS / non-FIPs mismatch, but as `SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` is FIPS 140-2 compatible, this is unlikely to be the cause. (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes)

Answer (score 1):

To add to @chughts answer, you can list the supported ciphers of the JVM you are using.

The following code is from https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html

I updated the code to included the JVM release information.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class Ciphers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Running under Java " + System.getProperty("java.version")
                            + " from " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        String[] defaultCiphers = ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        String[] availableCiphers = ssf.getSupportedCipherSuites();

        TreeMap<String, Boolean> ciphers = new TreeMap<String, Boolean>();

        for(int i=0; i<availableCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(availableCiphers[i], Boolean.FALSE);

        for(int i=0; i<defaultCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(defaultCiphers[i], Boolean.TRUE);

        System.out.println("Default\tCipher");
        for(Iterator i = ciphers.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry cipher=(Map.Entry)i.next();

            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(cipher.getValue()))
                System.out.print('*');
            else
                System.out.print(' ');

            System.out.print('\t');
            System.out.println(cipher.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it against 3 different JVMs and here is what I got for output:

(1)

```
Running under Java 1.8.0_341 from IBM Corporation
Default Cipher
*   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
*   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

(2)

```
Running under Java 1.8.0_201 from Oracle Corporation
Default Cipher
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

(3)

```
Running under Java 17.0.7 from Oracle Corporation
Default Cipher
*   TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```